# How to rsync to other directory

Tags: rsync

This is my rsync command

```
rsync --delete /src-dirname /dest-dirname
```

This creates

```
/dest-dirname/src-dirname
```

at the destination.

What I want is to sync all files and directories underneath `/src-dirname` to `/dest-dirname`,

This could be done by adding `/*` to the source, but at the same time `--delete` would no longer delete subdirectories at the destination (see [rsync won't delete files on destination](https://serverfault.com/questions/225140/rsync-wont-delete-files-on-destination)).

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without /* ?
 Please try the below command. You are missing / at the end. 
 rsync --delete /src-dirname/ /dest-dirname
Let us know if this worked too

Comment: Great! Using `/` instead of `/*` solves the problem.